# Change Unique ID of HDD

Tags: windows, powershell, hardware, hard-drive

I am attempting to implement a storage pool using window's Storage spaces UI. My problem is that the UI requires all hard drives to have different Unique ID's, and when there is a collision, the UI becomes useless. The problem was found in the Microsoft forum post:

- [Storage Spaces UI missing disks when a controller reports the same UniqueID for all attached disks (e.g. Supermicro AOC-SASLP-MV8)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/578a4c17-ed61-4d1a-837b-bdde46f2e7fe/storage-spaces-ui-missing-disks-when-a-controller-reports-the-same-uniqueid-for-all-attached-disks?forum=winserver8gen) *([archive](https://archive.fo/57Et4))*

**tl;dr:** I have multiple hard drives, some of which have the same Powershell Unique ID. Is there a way to change the Unique ID given by this powershell command:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-List FriendlyName, UniqueId, ObjectId, BusType
```

Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `UniqueID` is a device-id that includes vendor, model, bus and serial or something. So the ID is hardware specific. If your disk controller reports the same unique id for multiple disks, the solution is to get a new disk controller(or try a new firmware if it exists).